# Avoid adding a bunch of new features for one static location for repeat sampling efforts in Field Maps

Tags: geolocation, resampling, relates, sampling, arcgis-field-maps

I have built several maps and forms for their use in Field Maps for various projects. Most have been creating new features and filling out the form for the new location where we sampled. However, we now have a project that has static sampling locations and will be sampling at these exact sites repetitively. There is also past data for each static location to append which I will need to have at least 1 header named the same to append (site name etc.).

In Field Maps, I would like to select the sampling site and fill out a new form each time I sample. I also want to view a list of past data at the location. I do not want to create a new feature every time I sample at the site and create a cluster of points that are slightly off by GPS location. This makes it challenging and messy to view past data and enter new data for a static location.

I have resolved the data visualization on MapViewer by creating a cluster. That is not the problem. My problem is avoiding a pile of new features in one static sampling location. How would I go about resolving this issue? Would I need to download the file and open in Pro then use the Relate or Join tools based on a common header/field?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like using a related table would be the way to go for this. This task sounds a lot like the Field Maps tutorial project here: https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/inspect-hydrants/